# Building NetSieben's SSH Lib for C++

Tags: c++, ssh, botan

I have trying to build this library for quite a while and I am somewhat confused. I found it recommended on Stack Overflow (http://www.netsieben.com/products/ssh/index.phtml) but it only comes in Source packages. It also requires the Botan library to compile it, but I am at a loss.

I have installed Botan using the Windows Installer, as well as downloading the sourcecode. When I attempt to build it with CMAKE GUI, I get the following errors. I am not sure where I should be putting the Botan source so that it has access to it.

```
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Looking for C++ include botan/botan.h
Looking for C++ include botan/botan.h - not found
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    C:/ne7ssh-1.3.2/src

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.

  CMake does not support this case but it used to work accidentally and is
  being allowed for compatibility.

  Policy CMP0014 is not set: Input directories must have CMakeLists.txt.  Run
  "cmake --help-policy CMP0014" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:69 (install):
  install Library TARGETS given no DESTINATION!


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: According to the PDF file, NetSieben's SSH Library has available InstallShield packages, but I cannot find them on their site. Does anyone know where they are?

Answer (score 1):

Googling for the message "install Library TARGETS given no DESTINATION" indicates that removing the Library command on line 69 of CMakeLists.txt might work.

http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-September/023876.html